# EMCA insists that it cannot connect to the service

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, windows-server, oracle-enterprise-manager

Really new to Oracle and being a DBA in general. I am trying to set up a development environment so that I can play an learn oracle better. Enterprise Mananger failed to configure itself when I first created the database using the Database Configuration Assistant. No biggie. Just need to user emca.exe

I had some issues with the Listener but those might have just been me being impatient in waiting for the service to register or the service not running. Right now my issue is this from the emca log:

> ```
> CONFIG: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
> ```

According to post here and [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786782/ora-12514-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-service-requested-in-connect-d) it should just be an issue with the service name. Problem is it looks right to me.

#### Listener.ora

```
ADR_BASE_VLISTENER = D:\app\Administrator

VLISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = dvp-oracle)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

#### lsnrctl status

```
.... truncated ....
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=dvp-oracle)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "prodbkp" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "prodbkp", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "prodbkpXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "prodbkp", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

That tells me that the database registered itself dynamically correctly. prodbkp is my SID. This might be a case issue since I named the DB "PRODbkp" but everything else seems to be fine since I can connect with `sqlplus sys@prodbkp as sysdba` just fine. Case should not be an issue with service names as per [docs.oracle.com](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/syntax.htm#NETRF175)

#### tsnnames.ora

```
PRODBKP =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = dvp-oracle)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = prodbkp)
    )
  )
```

Which also looks OK. Most of the solutions point to SERVICE_NAME mismatches. However I don't *appear* to have one.

#### v$parameter output

```
SQL> select value from v$parameter where name='service_names';

VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

prodbkp
```

That gap you see above prodkbp is in the output as well. Not sure if that matters either. My production server has that anomaly as well so I can't imagine that has anything to do with it.

Basically everything looks right but something is still wrong. I cannot install Enterprise Manager

**Environment**

- Windows Server 2008R2
- Oracle 11g

Comment: This should be really easy to find in the log `D:\app\Administrator\diag\tnslsnr\vlistener\trace\vlistener.log`. Check that file and you will find what service name or SID emca uses to connect.

Comment: @BalazsPapp I see repetition of lines like this `(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=prodbkp)(CID=(PROGRAM=D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\sqlplus.exe)(HOST=DVP-ORACLE)(USER=Administrator))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=10.10.13.134)(PORT=49269))` which looks correct. I think I found the actual problem in listener.log. It looks like it was trying to connect to the host via the ipv6 address. I need to break it and test again to be sure I understood the issue first.

Comment: I'd probably need to fix service name to remove that newline or that empty service name, then bounce listener and then log on to db as sysdba and run 'alter system register;' and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

So it would seem the issue was not the service name specifically but that the request was going to the IPv6 address which was not set up in any of the required files. Looking at listener.log ( which for me was located D:\app\Administrator\diag\tnslsnr\dvp-oracle\listener\trace\listener.log) I found these entries associated to my connnection attempts.

```
28-AUG-2017 08:41:58 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=prodbkp)(CID=(PROGRAM=D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\sqlplus.exe)(HOST=DVP-ORACLE)(USER=Administrator))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=fe80::7197:6503:9e81:5454%11)(PORT=49246)) * establish * prodbkp * 0
```

The important portion was `HOST=fe80::7197:6503:9e81:5454%11`. Since I would never need to support IPv6 I removed it from the network adapter and restarted the server to ensure all services were updated accordingly.

While it might not be the ideal solution I was able to recreate the EM dbcontrol successfully after that change.